# Capture audio correctly while capturing video calls on MacBook with earbuds

Tags: bluetooth, screen-capture, microphone, ear-phones, video-capture

I'd like to capture video calls on my MacBook Pro, while I have my Bluetooth Earbuds connected. I use Zoom, Google Meet and Skype on different calls, so would like to use osX's native screen video capture capabilities. I can't seem to configure it in a way that captures both the video call audio and my microphone. Note I set settings/audio/input to the laptop's mic rather than the earhbuds' because it works better.

Searching online, it seems [I should use either **Aggregate Device** or **Multi-Output Device** or both](https://youtu.be/MGPF2nME_H8), but I'm not sure how to configure them correctly, especially as I can't install 3rd party drivers, as demonstrated in the video, because I'm using a work computer.

How do I perform this magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to install something, macOS can't do this on its own - in fact, as far as I'm aware, no OS can do this on its own; they all need some kind of routing utility.

I haven't used all of these, so I can't list them in any kind of 'best' order.
My personal favourite & the only one I really use these days is…

**[Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/)** - expensive for a one-trick pony, but like all things from Rogue Amoeba, it "just works".

*Later edit*
To make this list more comprehensive, Rogue Amoeba make several routing apps for slightly different purposes. Also check out [**Audio Hijack**](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) and [**SoundSource**](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/)

All below are ones I'm aware of but haven't used. They're mainly freeware/shareware/donationware

**[iShowU  Audio Capture](https://support.shinywhitebox.com/hc/en-us/articles/204161459-Installing-iShowU-Audio-Capture-Mojave-and-earlier-)**

> iShowU Audio Capture is an extension to OS X used by iShowU Studio and iShowU Instant to record audio from your computer. This new-and-improved audio driver replaces Soundflower and provides a bunch of new features and improvements in order to make recording audio more stable and easy to do.

[**Jack** Audio Connection Kit](https://jackaudio.org/downloads/)
Open source routing.

**[VB-CABLE Virtual Audio Device](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/)**
New to macOS, has been around a while on Windows.

> VB-CABLE is a virtual audio device working as virtual audio cable. All audio coming in the CABLE input is simply forwarded to the CABLE output.

**[Blackhole](https://existential.audio/blackhole/)**
New kid on the block.

> BlackHole is an open source virtual audio driver that allows applications to pass audio to other applications with zero additional latency.

**[Sound Siphon](https://staticz.com/soundsiphon/)** Paid.
Seems to be a straight copy of Loopback.

**[Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower)**
The original… updated for Catalina.

> MacOS system extension that allows applications to pass audio to other >applications. Soundflower works on macOS Catalina.

Soundflower used to be the go-to routing app for OS X but got less reliable over time. It was passed around between new owners for some time - initially Cycling '74, then Rogue Amoeba took a caretaker role for a while. It's now back in the hands of its original creator, Matt Ingalls. One essential part is missing compared to early versions, Soundflowerbed, which was the vital routing component. I haven't used it since the early days, when it was tough to set up but easy to work with once you had. Many people seem to struggle with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to download any additional software; all that's required is QuickTime, System Preferences, and Audio MIDI Setup (Applications > Utilities > Audio MIDI Setup, for the Multi-Output + Bluetooth headset).

To screen record WITH internal audio AND microphone voice over using QuickTime on a Mac (without downloading additional software) you will need a USB microphone and a Bluetooth headset + mic'd audio cable. This works even if you only have one audio port on your computer.

1. Plug the USB mic into the computer.
2. Plug the audio cable into the computer.
3. And the other end of the audio cable into the microphone.
4. Open System Preferences, set the Sound Output to USB, and Input to the Microphone port.

To listen through the headset while you screen record, there are a few more steps.

5. Connect the Bluetooth headset.
6. Open Audio MIDI Setup (Applications > Utilities), and create a Multi-Output Device, adding the headset with Built-in Output.
7. Go back to System Preferences and change the Sound Output to the new Multi-Output Device.
8. Open QuickTime to create a "New Screen Recording" setting the microphone option to Built-in.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkksiIDL5qU