# Apply audio filters (AU/VST plugins) to microphone for video conferencing

Tags: audio

I am looking for a way to apply filters (AU/VST plugins) to my microphone before using it for video conferencing.

I am able to do using [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) with my microphone as input, adding the filters and sending a new virtual audio device created using [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/).

While this works, it's very inconvenient and not suitable for daily use. That is why I am looking for an easier way to do this, not involving multiple applications that can be run in the background.

Currently running macOS Big Sur.

Comment: Can't you do this using *only* Audio Hijack, without Loopback? Open a session & it should auto-load all the required apps too. I honestly don't know of anything better than Rogue Amoeba for anything like this. Soundsource *would* be simpler, but you can only add VST/AU to outputs not inputs unfortunately. List of other routing apps, untested, but I doubt any of them are as comprehensive - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408600/capture-audio-correctly-while-capturing-video-calls-on-macbook-with-earbuds