# Advanced Audio Output

Tags: audio, headphones, speakers

Here is my setup: Two 27" displays directly next to each other, connected to a Mac mini. Both displays have built in speakers that get audio over displayport<->USBC.

So if I wanted the left most speaker (left speaker on left display) and right most speaker (right speaker on right display) to be my stereo left/right, that appears to be easy. Just create a multi-out device, and then adjust the audio balance on each display.

Is there a way to do that without adjusting the balance though? Can I break it up so each channel only goes to the exact speaker I want? That seems like the kind of thing you would do with an aggregate device but it's very unclear how you would do that, or anything, in the aggregate screen.

If I can do that, can I take it a step further? Can I emulate a 2.1 system in software, where left goes to the leftmost speaker, right goes to the rightmost speaker, and a mixed-to-mono, filtered bass-only signal would go to both middle speakers? This would be the most ideal setup. I know built in speakers aren't going to have much bass to begin with. All the more reason to double the amount by getting bass from all four speakers.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408600/capture-audio-correctly-while-capturing-video-calls-on-macbook-with-earbuds for a list of routing apps on Mac