# How to stream analog audio input to AirPods via Mac?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

There's a case where I need to play audio from software on my Mac, but also simultaneously from a Line In analog audio source using the 3.5mm audio jack on a 2021 MacBook Pro. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem the new machines still have an optical audio input, but the goal here is to hear the mixed audio from both the Mac and the external source on AirPods paired to the Mac.

So, a couple of questions:

1. Can the 3.5mm port function as a Line In, or only as a Microphone?
2. Is it possible that I can stream all system audio (including the external source) to AirPods (or theoretically the built-in speakers) while also hearing system software? Perhaps using a third-party app or some Homebrew hackery?

... Any thoughts here would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your second question makes no sense.  “System software?”  Are you referring to “system sounds?”  If that’s the case, then yes, you can send both audio and system alerts to the same device.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Apple Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP854), the 3.5mm port is a headphone (stereo speakers and microphone) port only.

If you need multiple sources, you need a proper audio interface like a [Behringer mixer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295628/119271).  This type of device will allow you to connect multiple analog and/or digital inputs so that you can better process them.  It has an internal DAC (digital analog converter) so that everything your Mac receives is digital and all digital outputs can be converted to analog for headphones/external speakers

Comment: Got it, so it sounds like with the omission of the optical side of things, it's no longer a "line in" option.

Comment: Cost cutting at its finest!

Comment: I think if there were a cable that converted 3.5mm optical audio to a USB-C audio source, that would probably solve the hardware side of this. It might exist, but seems unlikely.

Comment: Still wondering about literally just outputting audio to AirPods from there. 

Comment: Wow, the product actually does exist, not sure about quality ha: https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2255800058509457.html

Comment: Ben - the circuitry for basic ADCs/DACs was optimised decades ago. You're probably pretty safe even with one made from Chinesium these days. You **do** need to ensure you buy a TOSLink to USB [or bi-directional] though. That one's the wrong way round by the looks of it, USB to TOSLink. You'll need something from here to do the routing internally - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408600/capture-audio-correctly-while-capturing-video-calls-on-macbook-with-earbuds

Comment: Good callout! That's output only.